# Every time I open terminal I realize that zsh_history Symbolic Link has been deleted

Tags: terminal, zsh

Hey Guys I using zsh and moved my `.zshrc`,`.zsh_history` and `.oh-my-zsh` to the dropbox folder to back up them and use them everywhere, and I created a Symbolic Link to them to use them
but every time I create a Symbolic Link for`.zsh_history` I see that has been created but every time that I open the terminal and check home directory I see that `.zsh_history` file has no Symbolic Link.

and I use this command:

```
mv .zsh_history ~/Dropbox/ZSH_Backup/ && rm -f .zsh_history && ln -s ~/Dropbox/ZSH_Backup/.zsh_history ~
```

So what is the problem?

Comment: Zsh seems to rewrite history whenever it terminates, most likely this is considered to be a feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a common issue with zsh.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111730/45383

> The easiest way to do this would be to not use links at all. The location of the zsh history file is determined by the value of $HISTFILE. So, to have that backed up, change it from the default value to a file in the watched directory. Add this line to your .zshrc:

```
HISTFILE=$HOME/Dropbox/ZSH_Backup/.zsh_history
```

Comment: I don't think so because after adding it to .zshrc when I reboot the machine it happened again

Comment: @farshadb After adding that line it doesn’t matter what happens to your symlink because it’s not used any more.

Comment: so what should I do to make sure my symbolic link is safe?

Comment: @farshadb Your symlink doesn’t matter any more because it’s not used. You’ve told zsh what file to use as history.